# How to prove a subspace?

Tags: analysis

Let X be a Banach space and let M be a subset of X. Then M is itself
a Banach space (using the norm from X) if and only if M is closed subspace.

How to prove (=>) to show that M is closed subspace?

Question:If I have M is subset of X then I have M is a subspace???? If this statement is true, I can prove it.

Thanks. :-)

Comment: no. by subspace one usually denotes a linear subspace (i.e a vector subspace). The point is that a linear subspace need not be complete (in general). So you have to show that if it is complete (a Banach space wrt to the induced norm) then it is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $M$ is closed. You have to show $M$ is complete. Let $x_n$ be a Cauchy Sequence in $M$. Since $X$ is a Banach space, $x_n$ converges to some $x\in X$. Since $M$ is closed, $x\in M$. So $M$ is complete.

Suppose $M$ is a Banach space. You have to show $M$ is closed in $X$. Since $X$ is a normed space it suffices to show that, if $x_n$ is a sequence in $M$ which converges in $X$ to some $x\in X$, then if follows that $x\in M$. So suppose $x_n$ is convergent to $x$. Then $x_n$ is a Cauchy Sequence in $X$, but since $M$ carries the same norm, in $M$ as well. Since $M$ is a Banach space, $x_n$ converges in $M$ to $x^\prime \in M$. Since $M\subset X$ with the induced topology, $x_n\rightarrow x^\prime$ in $X$. By uniqueness of the limit, $x = x^\prime$, so $M$ is closed.

Answer (score -1):

To $M$ be a subspace you need that $\forall x,y,\in M $ and $\forall \alpha$ scalar

$x+y\in M$ 
and
$\alpha x \in M$.

But, it doesn't mean that $M$ is a Banach space. To be a Banach space one needs that $M$ be a complete space, that's why one requires that $M$ be closed.

To show that $M$ is closed you need to show that every Cauchy sequence converges to a point in $M$.

Comment: Could you please prove M is subspace of X ? I'm confused how to show $x+y$ belong in $M$ and $/alpha$ $x$ belong in M.

Comment: If think the question is wrong, probably the question should state that $M$ is a subspace, not only a subset, you need more information about $M$ to say that $M$ is a subspace.

Comment: "To show that $M$ is closed..." -- no. To show $M$ is closed you need to show that a convergent sequence $x_n\rightarrow x$  in X with $x_n\in M$ implies $x\in M$.

Comment: That's what I implicitly said, but you're correct, I should have state that I was refering to a Cauchy sequence in $M$

Comment: what you 'implicitly said' is what the OP actually is supposed to show.